# Fastest way to make a dict a single comma-separated string

Tags: python, string

I have a list of

```
uids: ['1234','4321','1111']
```

and I would like to turn this into a single string of:

```
"uid = '1234' OR uid = '4321' OR uid = '1111'"
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this for making an SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If—as Mike and Thomas mention in the comments—you need this for a database query, you should take Thomas' advice and use [the DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Here are two examples:

**MySQL**

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='u', passwd='p', db='mydb')
curs = conn.cursor()
uids = [1234,4321,1111]
qry = ("""SELECT cheese 
            FROM cheeseshop 
           WHERE id IN (%s)""" % ','.join(['%s']*len(uids)))
# 'SELECT cheese FROM cheeseshop WHERE id IN (%s,%s,%s)'
curs.execute(qry, uids)
curs.fetchone()
# ...
```

**SQLite**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
curs = conn.cursor()
uids = [1234,4321,1111]
qry = ("""SELECT cheese 
            FROM cheeseshop 
           WHERE id IN (%s)""" % ','.join('?'*len(uids)))
# 'SELECT cheese FROM cheeseshop WHERE id IN (?,?,?)'
curs.execute(qry, uids)
curs.fetchone()
# ...
```

Answer (score 9):

```
' OR '.join("uid = '%s'" % u for u in uids)
```

This invokes the `join` function on the string `' OR '`, which takes the list passed in and puts the string in between each element, then concatenates them all together. (Used to put the  ORs in between each key=val pair.)

The part inside the `()` is a comprehension that says "for each `u` in the `uids` list, generate a value equal to the string `"uid = '%s'"`, but substitute in `u` instead of the `%s` marker".

Comment: I don't think it gets any better than this. +1.

Comment: Keep in mind that if this is for a SQL statement, a better approach is to use DB-API quoting: put "uid = ?" (for the `qmark` paramstyle) in your SQL statement instead, one for each uid, separated by OR as above, and pass the list of uids (along with any other parameters) to the `execute` method. That way you won't have to worry about getting the quoting right.

Comment: @Thomas: Agreed. The day I discovered parameterized queries I jumped on them and never looked back.